# Does every level order traversal uniquely define a BST?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Suppose I have to compare whether two binary search trees are similar. Now, the basic approach is the recursive formulation that checks for the root to be equal and then continues to check the equality of the corresponding right and left subtrees.

However, will it be correct to state that if the binary search trees have the same level order traversals then they are the same? Stated differently, does every BST have a unique level order traversal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't.

The first one:

```
1
 \
  \
   2
    \
     \
      3
```

The second:

```
   1
  / \
 /   \
2     3
```

Level order will give 1 - 2 - 3 for these two.

Since the informational theory lower bound on representing a binary tree with n nodes is `2n - THETA(log n)`, I don't think any simple traversal should be able to identify a binary tree.

Google search confirms the lower bound:

[lower bound bits  binary tree](https://www.google.com/#biw=1029&bih=516&sclient=psy-ab&q=lower+bound+bits++binary+tree&oq=lower+bound+bits++binary+tree&gs_l=hp.3..33i29i30l2.236.2022.2.2300.12.12.0.0.0.0.215.1286.6j5j1.12.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.i2w2D74OBrE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.dmg&fp=922e862274675230)

There is a simple reduction from BST to binary tree. Consider the BSTs with nodes value 1..n. The number of these BSTs is the number of binary trees with n nodes (you could always do a pre order traversal and insert the value in that order). If you can use a level order traversal to identify such a BST, you can use 1 for a "in-level" node, 0 for a "end-level" node. The first tree becomes "000", the second one "010". This will let a BST be identified with just n bits, with does not fit the information theory lower bound.

Comment: What if we talk of Binary Search Trees? The answer you gave is for Binary Trees.

Comment: @NikunjBanka A simple reduction will do. Edited.

Comment: Can you please give an example where two different BSTs have the same inorder traversals ?

Comment: I similarly couldn't come up with any examples of BSTs that have the same level order. Are you sure your reduction is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well , I discussed this question with a friend of mine , so the answer isn't exactly mine! , but here's what came up, the level order traversal you do for a BST can be sorted and thus you can get the inorder traversal of the particular BST. Now you get two traversals which can then be used to uniquely identify the BST. Thus it wouldn't be incorrect to state that every BST has a unique level order traversal.

Algorithm:

```
ConstructBST(levelorder[] , int Size)
   1. Declare array A of size n.
   2. Copy levelorder into A
   3. Sort A
   From two traversals A and levelorder of a Binary Search Tree , of which one is inorder, construct the tree.
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "the level order traversal you do for a BST can be sorted" ? The level order traversal of BST produces a sorted result only when all nodes in the BST have no left pointers. What you are pointing out is only for the special case that I just mentioned. I don't think that we can conclusively say something just on the basis of one special case.